# Database Selecting two tables

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to select two tables with no luck.I can search 1 fine but i want to search two table both have a common field called name i have the following code:

```
...
myConnection.Open()
Dim strg As String
strg = "SELECT * FROM Table1,Table4 WHERE Name=@Name"
```

is this possible? What am i doing wrong here? any help would be great.
I am using visual studio 2010 on windows 7 enterprise x32.

Comment: What do you want the result table to look like?  Should it have all the columns from `Table1` and `Table4`?

Comment: no only matching ones

Comment: You want to include all rows from `Table1` and `Table4` where the `Name` column equals `@Name`?

Comment: yes i can get a value from  table 1 if NAME matchs NAME but i want to check table4 at the same time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Table1 and Table4 have same columns you can write it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name=@Name
union
SELECT * FROM Table4 WHERE Name=@Name
```

Comment: this seemed to want to work but i am get an error (0x80040E14):The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a union query do not match.

Comment: I changed this code a little and i think its working its not throwing any errors on me yet. `SELECT Name FROM Table1 WHERE Name=@Name
union
SELECT Name FROM Table4 WHERE Name=@Name`